# How to create two dimensional lists?

Tags: python, list

How can I create a 2 dimensional list in Python? I'm new to arrays and lists and am getting mixed results with dimensional lists, so I would like to know a way how to do the example down below.

```
enter a number between [3,9]:  4

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12],[0, 4, 8, 12, 16]]

0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 4
0 2 4 6 8
0 3 6 9 12
0 4 8 12 16
```

Comment: Lists are one-dimensional, period. You can *nest* lists to simulate two-dimensional data structures, but you can only index the outer layer, then index the result separately. NumPy provides multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's to ask the user for an integer aka ```n``` between ```3``` to ```9``` so it can validate the input.

Comment: @Chepner, yes, however, a list of lists is by definition a 2 dimensional list.  Is there a way without imports?

Comment: @KPS No, it isn't. A two-dimensional list can be indexed in either dimension; e.g., you can index a NumPy array with something like `a[:,0]` to get the first column. For a list, you would have to write something like `[a[i][0] for i in range(len(a))]`. There's also no way to enforce that each nested list has the same length as the purported second dimension.

Comment: @chepner I see, according to what I've been lectured on, dimensional lists usually require 2 nested loops by moving across the row and one down the column. They also said something about creating a list that contains the times tables from ```0*0``` up to ```n*n```.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import numpy as np

x = 5
l = np.array(range(x))
r = [l*i for i in range(x)]
```

Comment: Is there a way without the import?

Answer (score 1):

Seems, two loops from 0 upto n+1 make the result

```
n = 4
[[i*j for i in range(n+2)] for j in range(n+2)]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], 
 [0, 3, 6, 9, 12], 
 [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]]
```

Comment: I tried to run this in Python to see the example, but nothing appeared.

Comment: the output is from a Python shell. Have you printed the result list?

Comment: how can I print the result list?

Comment: `print([[i*j for i in range(n+2)] for j in range(n+2)])`